# Class constructor asks for 'customPredicate: Message.() -> Boolean' and I cant figure out what is it mean

Tags: kotlin, telegram-bot

I have an the following Interface

```
interface Filter {
    fun checkFor(message: Message): Boolean = message.predicate()
    fun Message.predicate(): Boolean

infix fun and(otherFilter: Filter): Filter = object : Filter {
    override fun Message.predicate(): Boolean =
        this@Filter.checkFor(this) && otherFilter.checkFor(this)
}

infix fun or(otherFilter: Filter): Filter = object : Filter {
    override fun Message.predicate(): Boolean =
        this@Filter.checkFor(this) || otherFilter.checkFor(this)
}

operator fun not(): Filter = object : Filter {
    override fun Message.predicate(): Boolean = !this@Filter.checkFor(this)
}

class Custom(private val customPredicate: Message.() -> Boolean) : Filter {
    override fun Message.predicate(): Boolean = customPredicate()
}

object All : Filter {
    override fun Message.predicate(): Boolean = true
}
```

In this Interface I have a class named "Custom"
which ask in the constructor for

```
class Custom(private val customPredicate: Message.() -> Boolean)
```

And I have no idea how should I use this class to create my own Filter

Please assist

Comment: `I have no idea how should I use this class to create my own Filter` you've no idea, how to create an object of `Custom` class or how to create a `filter`?

Comment: @Praveen how to create the object `Custom`

Comment: See [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few ways you can create an object of `Custom` class.

You can use the `lambda` expression as a function with the receiver, the receiver is available inside the body as `context`.

```
val custom = Custom { //lambda begins here
    //here you can call any method of Message, which is the receiver
}
```

---

You can create an extension function of `Message` and pass its reference to the `Custom` class constructor.

```
fun Message.customPredicate() {
    // Your code here
}
```

Pass reference of this function to the `constructor` of the `Custom` class

```
val custom = Custom(Message::customPredicate)
```

---

You can also use an anonymous function for creating an `object` of the `Custom` class.

```
val custom = Custom(fun Message.() {
    // Your code here
})
```